# Need to press key twice after exception - Python tkinter

Tags: python, exception, tkinter, events

newbie here.

I'm using tkinter for this.

In below code label text immediately updates when key 1, 2 or 3 is pressed. When another regular key (like 'k' or '5') is pressed before, it also immediately updates.

But, now **the problem**: when a special key (like Alt) is pressed before, it only updates when first any key is pressed, and then 1, 2 or 3. Like you need to press twice after a special key is pressed.

In code below try/except is used to ignore ValueError of special key input.

What I want is that the label text always immediately updates no matter what key is pressed before.

Please share how to do this, thanks!

```
from tkinter import *

def getKey(event):
    
    userIn=''
    
    try:
        
        if event.char in '1 2 3':
            userIn = event.char 
            l['text'] = userIn
            
    except:
        pass    
    

root = Tk()
l = Label(root, text='input')
l.pack()
root.bind('<Key>', getKey)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `<KeyRelease>` instead of `<Key>`.  Or add `return "break"` at the end of `getKey()`.

Comment: Using keyRelease seems to do exactly what you want, and you can remove the try except block

Comment: @RolvApneseth If there is `try` there should be an `except` block.

Comment: @acw1668 Using <KeyRelease> seems to work best, thanks! If try/except block is removed then label text turns empty after pressing special key twice.

Comment: You should use `event.char in ['1','2','3']` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `<KeyRelease>` instead of `<Key>` (which is the same as `<KeyPress>`).

Also `event.char in '1 2 3'` is `True` when `event.char` is either `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, `' '` and empty string.  So pressing special key (which cause `event.char` is empty) will clear the text.  Use `event.char in ['1','2','3']` instead.

```py
from tkinter import *

def getKey(event):
    if event.char in ['1', '2', '3']:
        l['text'] = event.char
    
root = Tk()

l = Label(root, text='input')
l.pack()

root.bind('<KeyRelease>', getKey)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: " Also event.char in '1 2 3' is True when event.char is either '1', '2', '3', ' ' and empty string "
to confirm, is this because there are spaces between '1 2 3'?